# Hbase Stargate REST Interface: How to encode a scanner with filter in XML?

Tags: rest, hbase, stargate

I'm using Hbase over Stargate and want to use a scanner with certain filters. In java or thrift, this would be no problem, but I don't find any advice how to encode the filters in XML. The Schema given in the wiki is invalid, so I'd need one or two Examples how to encode those filters (with AND/OR) in XML.